# midi application on smartphone

Tags: midi, smartphone

What tools should I use to create an application using midi sounds for a smartphone ?
Witch os should be more appropriate ? iphone/android/windows ?

Thanks

Comment: Nice idea, but is there any hardware for that? I'm trembling with terror when thinking about the latencies of anything related to sound processing over any kind of wireless.

Comment: Well, if you root an android phone, you can get access to the USB port on the phone... meaning that you can install several open source Midi drivers, one of which should work.  Link: http://sven.killig.de/android/N1/2.2/usb_host/

Answer (score 0):

The Core MIDI framework was made available on iOS devices starting with 4.2. Certain existing USB MIDI accessories are already known to work using the iPad and Apple Camera Connection Kit, and MIDI accessories that will work with all Apple devices running iOS 4.2 or later (i.e. iPhone, iPod Touch, and iPad - not just iPad) are on the way. Core MIDI also works over 802.11 wifi.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CACoreMIDIRef/_index.html